# Creating a body for Alamofire POST request Swift 4

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, post, alamofire

I need help with creating a custom body when sending POST request with Alamofire.

I'm sending to API products. There are two types of products. First type has just quantity, second one - different quantities(`size_id`) and quantities that match each `size_id`.

Final body should look like:

```
"factory_id": "1"

"order_products[0][product_id]": "1"
"order_products[0][size_id]": "2"
"order_products[0][quantity]": "10"

"order_products[1][product_id]": "1"
"order_products[1][size_id]": "3"
"order_products[1][quantity]": "10"

"order_products[1][product_id]": "2"
"order_products[1][size_id]": "2"
"order_products[1][quantity]": "10"

"order_products[2][product_id]": "3"
"order_products[2][quantity]": "10"
```

Here's what I achieved so far:

```
var createOrderBody = [String: Any]()
let productIds = ["1", "2", "3"]
var body = [String: Any]()
var quantity = ["1" : "10", "2": "10"]
var noIdQuantity = ["10"]
var finalBody = [String: Any]()

func formBody(products: String, factoryId: String, productId: String, size_id: String, quantity: String) -> [String: Any] {

    createOrderBody["factory_id"] = factoryId
    createOrderBody["order_products[\(products)][product_id]"] = productId
    createOrderBody["order_products[\(products)][size_id]"] = size_id
    createOrderBody["order_products[\(products)][quantity]"] = quantity

    return createOrderBody
}

for (index, value) in productIds.enumerated() {

    for (id, size) in quantity {
        print(id)
        print(size)
        body = formBody(products: String(index), factoryId: "1", productId: String(value), size_id: id, quantity: size)
        print("Body quantity - ", body)
    }
}
```

And the result I have is:

```
"factory_id": "1",

"order_products[0][product_id]": "1"
"order_products[0][size_id]": "2", 
"order_products[0][quantity]": "10",

"order_products[1][product_id]": "2",
"order_products[1][size_id]": "2",  
"order_products[1][quantity]": "10",

"order_products[2][product_id]": "3",
"order_products[2][size_id]": "2", 
"order_products[2][quantity]": "10",
```

As you can see, I have almost achieved desired result, but the problem is that it is adding only last element of `quantity` dictionary and omits other values. Also, I don't know how to add quantity to the product, that doesn't have `size_id`

Also, I know that it is not a good practice to place `for in` loop inside other `for in` loop  but I'm new to development and this is the best idea that I have came up with.

Would be grateful for any help with this issue, as I've been battling with it almost for a week right now.

Many thanks and have a nice weekends!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After studying and searching on the Internet, here's a solution to the issue we have here. For reference, original post here - [Original Post](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/335570)

Assuming that every product has to hold it's own quantity:

We can define a struct like this:

```
struct Product {  
    let id: String  
    let quantities: [(sizeId: String, quantity: Int)]?  
    let noIdQuantity: Int?  

    init(id: String, quantities: [(sizeId: String, quantity: Int)]) {  
        self.id = id  
        self.quantities = quantities  
        self.noIdQuantity = nil  
    }  

    init(id: String, quantity: Int) {  
        self.id = id  
        self.quantities = nil  
        self.noIdQuantity = quantity  
    }  
}
```

With the struct above, we just need only one input variable and one output variable:

```
// Define input `product with id` as an Array of `Product`  
let products = [  
    Product(id: "1", quantities: [("1", 10), ("2", 10)]),  
    Product(id: "2", quantities: [("1", 10), ("2", 10)]),  
    Product(id: "3", quantities: [("1", 15), ("2", 20)]),  
    Product(id: "4", quantity: 10),  
]  
// Output dictionary  
var body = [String: Any]()
```

To make entries for a single Product into a Dictionary:

```
extension Product {  
    func formBody(_ index: inout Int, into body: inout [String: Any]) {  
        if let quantities = self.quantities {  
            for (sizeId, quantity) in quantities {  
                body["order_products[\(index)][product_id]"] = self.id  
                body["order_products[\(index)][size_id]"] = sizeId  
                body["order_products[\(index)][quantity]"] = quantity  
                index += 1  
            }  
        }  
        if let quantity = self.noIdQuantity {  
            body["order_products[\(index)][product_id]"] = self.id  
            body["order_products[\(index)][quantity]"] = quantity  
            index += 1  
        }  
    }  
}
```

And use them as follows:

```
var index = 0  
body["factory_id"] = "1"  
for product in products {  
    product.formBody(&index, into: &body)  
}  
print("Body quantity - ", body)  
body.sorted {$0.key < $1.key}.forEach{print("\($0.key)=\($0.value)")} //For showing readable result, not for Alammofire body
```

So, the final result would be:

```
factory_id=1
order_products[0][product_id]=1
order_products[0][quantity]=10
order_products[0][size_id]=1
order_products[1][product_id]=1
order_products[1][quantity]=10
order_products[1][size_id]=2
order_products[2][product_id]=2
order_products[2][quantity]=10
order_products[2][size_id]=1
order_products[3][product_id]=2
order_products[3][quantity]=10
order_products[3][size_id]=2
order_products[4][product_id]=3
order_products[4][quantity]=15
order_products[4][size_id]=1
order_products[5][product_id]=3
order_products[5][quantity]=20
order_products[5][size_id]=2
order_products[6][product_id]=4
order_products[6][quantity]=10
```

Hope this helps someone, who has same complex structure or similar.